How to persist entities in @ManyToMany relationship with @EmbeddedId
I am using Spring Boot 3. I have 2 entities in @ManyToMany relationship: Meeting (table name is 'meeting') and Document (table name is 'document'), the relationship table is 'relation_document_meeting'. What I want to do is, when I save a new Meeting and a related new Document (both of them have no ID), Hibernate will create 2 new records, 1 in 'meeting' and 1 in 'document', as well as a new record in 'relation_document_meeting'. Below is my entities:
Entity Meeting:
@Data
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "meeting")
@Accessors(chain = true)
@SuppressWarnings("common-java:DuplicatedBlocks")
public class Meeting extends AbstractAuditingEntity<Long> implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "sequenceGenerator")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "sequenceGenerator")
@Column(name = "id")
private Long id;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "meeting", orphanRemoval = true)
private List<RelDocumentMeeting> documents = new ArrayList<>();

public void addDocument(Document document, boolean isMain) {
    if (this.documents.stream().noneMatch(relDocument -> relDocument.getDocument().equals(document))) {
        RelDocumentMeeting relDocumentMeeting = new RelDocumentMeeting(document, this, isMain);
        documents.add(relDocumentMeeting);
        document.getMeetings().add(relDocumentMeeting);
    }
}

Entity Document:
@Data
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "document")
@Accessors(chain = true)
@SuppressWarnings("common-java:DuplicatedBlocks")
public class Document implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "sequenceGenerator")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "sequenceGenerator")
@Column(name = "id")
private Long id;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "document", orphanRemoval = true)
private List<RelDocumentMeeting> meetings = new ArrayList<>();

Entity RelDocumentMeeting (the relationship entity)
@Data
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@Accessors(chain = true)
@Table(name = "relation_document_meeting")
public class RelDocumentMeeting extends AbstractAuditingEntity<RelDocumentMeetingId> implements Serializable {

@EmbeddedId
private RelDocumentMeetingId id;

@ManyToOne
@MapsId("documentId")
private Document document;

@ManyToOne
@MapsId("meetingId")
private Meeting meeting;

@Column(name = "main")
private boolean main = false;

The EmbeddedId
@Data
@Embeddable
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class RelDocumentMeetingId implements Serializable {

@Column(name = "document_id", nullable = false)
private Long documentId;

@Column(name = "meeting_id", nullable = false)
private Long meetingId;

Now, when I do persist a couple of new Meeting and Document (both have no ID), it throws an error
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: Could not set value of type [org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGeneratorHelper$1]: 'com.domain.RelDocumentMeetingId.meetingId' (setter)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:341)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:241)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:550)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:335)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:152)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:135)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:220)
Caused by: org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: Could not set value of type [org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGeneratorHelper$1]: 'com.kd.sma.domain.RelDocumentMeetingId.meetingId' (setter)
    at org.hibernate.property.access.spi.SetterFieldImpl.set(SetterFieldImpl.java:88)
    at org.hibernate.id.CompositeNestedGeneratedValueGenerator.generate(CompositeNestedGeneratedValueGenerator.java:140)
    at org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerator.generate(IdentifierGenerator.java:147)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.generateId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:153)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:124)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:175)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.persist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:93)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:77)
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:138)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persistOnFlush(SessionImpl.java:818)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.CascadingActions$8.cascade(CascadingActions.java:333)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.CascadingActions$8.cascade(CascadingActions.java:323)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:517)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:439)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:224)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeCollectionElements(Cascade.java:551)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeCollection(Cascade.java:481)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:442)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:224)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:157)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.cascadeOnFlush(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:161)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.prepareEntityFlushes(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:144)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEverythingToExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:79)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultAutoFlushEventListener.onAutoFlush(DefaultAutoFlushEventListener.java:52)
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:127)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.autoFlushIfRequired(SessionImpl.java:1366)
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.lambda$new$2(ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.java:136)
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.withCacheableSqmInterpretation(ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.java:362)
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.performList(ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.java:303)
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.QuerySqmImpl.doList(QuerySqmImpl.java:509)
    at org.hibernate.query.spi.AbstractSelectionQuery.list(AbstractSelectionQuery.java:427)
    at org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:120)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$ExistsExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:315)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:92)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:149)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:137)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:170)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:158)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:164)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:143)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:70)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:392)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137)
    ... 60 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set java.lang.Long field com.domain.RelDocumentMeetingId.meetingId to org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGeneratorHelper$1
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:167)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:171)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.set(UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.java:81)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.set(Field.java:799)
    at org.hibernate.property.access.spi.SetterFieldImpl.set(SetterFieldImpl.java:57)
    ... 107 common frames omitted

How I'm adding meeting
Meeting meeting = new Meeting();
Document document = new Document();
meeting.addDocument(document, true);
meetingRepository.save(meeting);

Is there anyway to do it? Or I have to persist one side of relationship first?

Stop using @Data that will lead to issues (with hashCode and equals and toString). How are you adding documents to meetings? Make sure you are setting both sides of the relation into the RelDocumentMeeting class.

@M.Deinum I edited my code and added the method addDocument() that shows how I'm adding documents to meeting.
Besides, I created my own hashCode and equals and toString methods, so that @Data is fine, I think so

How are you saving things?

@M.Deinum I simply call MeetingRepository.save() method

Please add some code showing the saving also please add the full stacktrace you get.

@M.Deinum I added

That still doesn't look like the full stacktrace. But it appears to be an issue with the setter of the id class.

@M.Deinum I added full stacktrace

The error occurs because Hibernate is unable to set the composite key (RelDocumentMeetingId) correctly when persisting the RelDocumentMeeting entity. This is because the id field in RelDocumentMeeting relies on values (meetingId and documentId) from Meeting and Document, but neither of these IDs has been generated at the time Hibernate attempts to persist the relationship entity.
To resolve this issue, you need to ensure that Meeting and Document are saved and have their IDs generated before creating and persisting the RelDocumentMeeting entity. Here's how you can do this:
Updated Code
Save Meeting and Document first: Explicitly persist Meeting and Document entities to ensure they have IDs before associating them in the RelDocumentMeeting entity.

Refactor the addDocument method: Modify the method to ensure it is used after the Meeting and Document entities are saved.

Here’s how you can refactor and use the entities:
Refactor addDocument Method
public void addDocument(Document document, boolean isMain) {
    // Create the relationship only if the document is not already linked
    if (this.documents.stream().noneMatch(relDocument -> relDocument.getDocument().equals(document))) {
        RelDocumentMeeting relDocumentMeeting = new RelDocumentMeeting();
        relDocumentMeeting.setMeeting(this);
        relDocumentMeeting.setDocument(document);
        relDocumentMeeting.setMain(isMain);

        // Add to respective collections
        this.documents.add(relDocumentMeeting);
        document.getMeetings().add(relDocumentMeeting);
    }
}

Usage in Service/Controller Layer
Ensure you save the entities properly:
public void createMeetingWithDocument() {
    Meeting meeting = new Meeting();
    Document document = new Document();

    // Save meeting and document to generate IDs
    meeting = meetingRepository.save(meeting);
    document = documentRepository.save(document);

    // Add document to the meeting
    meeting.addDocument(document, true);

    // Save the meeting again to persist the relationship
    meetingRepository.save(meeting);
}

Key Changes:

Save Meeting and Document separately before establishing their relationship.
Use the IDs generated during the save operation for creating the composite key in RelDocumentMeeting.

